# Excel VBA For then loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have created this code which seem to work fine except that I would like to add the respective sales amount in columns F to I under each appropriate heading.

I have tried multiple expressions without any luck, can some please assist?

[image]

```
Sub OfficeListByLocation()

  Dim LoopCounter As Long
  Dim NumberOfCells As Long
  Dim Branch As String
  Dim Location As String
  Dim E As Long
  Dim W As String
  Dim N As String
  Dim S As String
  Dim Sales As Long

  Worksheets("OfficeList").Activate

  NumberOfCells = Range("A3", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Count

  For LoopCounter = 1 To NumberOfCells

    Branch = Range("A2").Offset(LoopCounter, 3).Text
    Sales = Range("A2").Offset(LoopCounter, 1).Value
    E = Range("A2").Offset(LoopCounter, 2).Value

     If Branch = "Miami" And Cells(3, 2).Value > 0 Then
       Location = "East"

     ElseIf Branch = "Melbourne" Then
       Location = "West"
       'W = "West"

     ElseIf Branch = "Jax" Then
        Location = "North"
        'N = "North"

     Else
        Location = "South"
        'S = "South"

     End If
     Range("A2").Offset(LoopCounter, 4).Value = Location

  Next LoopCounter    
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to work on your indentation. Why on earth would you indent Dim statements??? But then you DON'T indent loops and If statements???? Do you know what indentation is for?

Comment: Use MATCH to identify the position of the location in your the list of 4, and then place the figure in the corresponding position of the relevant row.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion SJR, it's highly appreciated